# How to save merged image inside folder in PHP?

Tags: php

I have to merge two images into one single image through PHP code. For that, I used the GD library of PHP. By using it I have merged the images and got one single image. Now what I want is to save the merged image into a folder and want to get the folder URL.
Here is the code which I used to merge the images:-

```
function mergeImages($images)
{
    $imageData = array();
    $len       = count($images);
    $wc        = ceil(sqrt($len));
    $hc        = floor(sqrt($len/2));
    $maxW      = array();
    $maxH      = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
    {
        $imageData[$i] = getimagesize($images[$i]);
        $found = false;
        for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++)
        {
            if ( $imageData[$maxW[$j]][0] < $imageData[$i][0] )
            {
                $farr = $j > 0 ? array_slice($maxW, $j-1, $i) : array();
                $maxW = array_merge($farr, array($i), array_slice($maxW, $j));
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( !$found )
        {
            $maxW[$i] = $i;
        }
        $found = false;
        for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++)
        {
            if ( $imageData[$maxH[$j]][1] < $imageData[$i][1] )
            {
                $farr = $j > 0 ? array_slice($maxH, $j-1, $i) : array();
                $maxH = array_merge($farr, array($i), array_slice($maxH, $j));
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( !$found )
        {
            $maxH[$i] = $i;
        }
    }
    $width = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $wc; $i++)
    {
        $width += $imageData[$maxW[$i]][0];
    } 
    $height = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $hc; $i++)
    {
        $height += $imageData[$maxH[$i]][1];
    }
    $im         = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $wCnt       = 0;
    $startWFrom = 0;
    $startHFrom = 0;
    for( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++ )
    {
        $tmp = imagecreatefromjpeg($images[$i]);     
        imagecopyresampled($im, $tmp, $startWFrom, $startHFrom, 0, 0, $imageData[$i][0], $imageData[$i][1], $imageData[$i][0], $imageData[$i][1]);  
        $wCnt++;
        if ( $wCnt == $wc )
        {
            $startWFrom = 0;
            $startHFrom += $imageData[$maxH[0]][1];
            $wCnt = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $startWFrom += $imageData[$i][0];
        }
    } 
    return $im;
}
$im = mergeImages(array('https://example.com/image_uploads/1634073799779802772384.jpg?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D1634073799779802772384&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAVCLDZENWTCRKLOWK%2F20220111%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220111T051751Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=518400&X-Amz-Signature=bb6d0d1f3d00396033f7de6faef94c8bb97a36d3dda9407ffa9f1a68a72235e5',
 'https://example.com/image_uploads/1634143552519639503004.jpg?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D1634143552519639503004&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAVCLDZENWTCRKLOWK%2F20220111%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220111T051751Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=518400&X-Amz-Signature=6d116cc87fb784cbaa870b13dce339f27392057cf8c2bb4ad552ac7c2df64704'));
header('Content-type: image/jpg');

imagejpeg($im);
```

Please help me out how would I save the merged image inside the folder.

Comment: Which particular part are you having trouble with? It seems to me that you have the image in `$im`, so isn't it just a case of using `file_put_contents()` to store it in the appropriate place, and then put that filename in the database?

Comment: Can you not append the filepath to `imagejpeg($im,'/path/to/save/img.jpg');` etc but remove the `header`

Comment: @droopsnoot I have used the file_put_contents() to store the image, but it doesn't seem to work and also I am getting the image name with the .php extension.

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't seem to work" please? Does it store the file in the wrong place, not store it at all, store it but with corrupted (or no) contents? I don't know what you mean about "getting the image name with the .php extension" - your code ends by outputting the image contents to the browser, so that will result in your browser showing the image but showing the script name in the address bar. That doesn't mean it will save with that name. Edit your post to show how you used `file_put_contents()` please.

Comment: @droopsnoot It is not storing the image in the folder.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I have tried your solution and it worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @droopsnoot Also thank you for giving me your precious time.

Comment: Glad that solved your problem, good luck]#